# Try to use a single class variable in template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

enum Creature { human, dog };

template <Creature Cr, unsigned AGE=0, typename T = void>
struct has_drive_perm {

    constexpr static bool perm = false;
};

template<unsigned AGE>
struct has_drive_perm<Creature::human, AGE, typename std::enable_if<!(AGE<=17),void>::type> {

    constexpr static bool perm = true;
};


template <typename CrT>
void check_drive_perm(CrT& creature);

template <unsigned AGE>
class Dog {

    public:
        typedef has_drive_perm<Creature::dog,AGE> tag;

        Dog(const std::string& name): name{name} {};
        static unsigned not_allowed_count;
        friend void check_drive_perm<Dog<AGE>>(Dog<AGE>&);

    private:
        typename std::enable_if<!tag::perm,void>::type check_can_drive() { std::cout<<"Dogs can't drive, stupid... and so does "<<name<<". It's the "<<not_allowed_count++<<"th time you ask smth like that!"<<std::endl; }
        //typename std::enable_if<!tag::perm,void>::type check_can_drive() { std::cout<<"Dogs can't drive, stupid... and so does "<<name<<std::endl; };//std::cout<<"It's the "<<not_allowed_count++<<"th time you ask smth like that!"<<std::endl; }
        const std::string name;
};

template <unsigned AGE, bool B=has_drive_perm<Creature::human,AGE>::perm>//=std::enable<has_drive_perm<Creature::human,AGE>::perm>
class Human {

    public:
        typedef has_drive_perm<Creature::human,AGE> tag;

        Human(const std::string& name): name{name} {};
        //static unsigned not_allowed_count;
        friend void check_drive_perm<Human<AGE,B>>(Human<AGE,B>&);

    private:
        void check_can_drive() { std::cout<<"Nope, "<<name <<" does not have a licence"<<std::endl; };
        const std::string name;
};

template <unsigned AGE>
class Human<AGE, true> {

    public:
        typedef has_drive_perm<Creature::human,AGE> tag;

        Human(const std::string& name): name{name} {};
        //static unsigned not_allowed_count;
        friend void check_drive_perm<Human<AGE,true>>(Human<AGE,true>&);

    private:
        void check_can_drive() { std::cout<<"Yep, "<<name <<" has a licence"<<std::endl; };
        const std::string name;
};

template <unsigned AGE>
unsigned Dog<AGE>::not_allowed_count;
//template <unsigned AGE>
//unsigned Human<AGE>::not_allowed_count;

template <typename CrT>
void check_drive_perm(CrT& creature) {

       creature.check_can_drive();
}

int main() {

    Dog<5> d1("John");
    Dog<10> d2("Jim");
    Human<18> h1("Marcus");
    Human<7> h2("Frank");

    check_drive_perm(d1);
    check_drive_perm(d2);
    check_drive_perm(h1);
    check_drive_perm(h2);
}
```

This gives me:

```
Dogs can't drive, stupid... and so does John. It's the 0th time you ask smth like that!
Dogs can't drive, stupid... and so does Jim. It's the 0th time you ask smth like that!
Yep, Marcus has a licence
Nope, Frank does not have a licence
```

I want to use the static class variable not_allowed_count only once, so that it would count up. But as I am instantiating the `dog class` with two different `AGE` params, I get two variants of the same class (is that true? Wouldn't the compiler then complain that I have a redefinition of the class dog?).
So my question is:

***How is it possible to use only one static class variable not_allowed_count?***

I thought of the CRTP-pattern but that only works on types and not on non-type template parameters (?)

Comment: `Dog<5>` is of a different type than `Dog<10>`, hence - the `static` variables that you keep incrementing are different. Why do you pass the age as a template argument, rather than constructor argument, in the first place? In my opinion, hat would make more sense.

Comment: Yep, I suspected that in my question: `But as I am instantiating the dog class with two different AGE params, I get two variants of the same class`. I know I could have also solved this with e.g. dynamic polymorphism, but I tried it statically and am now curious on how to find a construct that creates the static variable only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use static members of templated class to calculate usage of this class with any template arguments.

n3242 14.7.1/6

> Each class template specialization instantiated from a template has
>   its own copy of any static members.

If you want use static variable you can use inheritance for example.

```
 class not_allowed_counter
 {
 public:
    static unsigned not_allowed_count;
 };

 unsigned not_allowed_counter::not_allowed_count;

 template <unsigned AGE>
 class Dog : public not_allowed_counter {
    //
         typename std::enable_if<!tag::perm,void>::type check_can_drive() 
         {
            const unsigned not_allowed_count = static_cast<not_allowed_counter*>(this)->not_allowed_count++;
            std::cout<<"Dogs can't drive, stupid... and so does "<<name<<". It's the "<<not_allowed_count <<"th time you ask smth like that!"<<std::endl; 
         }
  }
```

Comment: Ok, that's a solution. But there would be a danger if I wanted to restrict this counter only to `class Dog` and if there were another class that also inherits from `not_allowed_counter` (thus modifying the static class variable as well)

Comment: @FloriHe ye. But you can solve it also with making `not_allowed_counter` templated. Well, there are different solutions.

Comment: Correct. I could create a base template with `template <Creature Cr>`, and then specializing it via `<>...<Human>` etc. thus getting different copies.

Comment: @FloriHe no need to specialize. Just intantiate.

Comment: As the behaviour isn't dependable of the template parameter in this case, there is no need for specialization,... again true.